# Android - Button's textColor with a selector not working

Tags: android, button, textcolor

I am trying to use a selector as button's textColor. But, for some reasons, the textColor becomes pink. I've searched a lot but couldn't find any solution for this case.

main_button_text_color.xml

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:state_focused="true" android:drawable="@android:color/black"/>
    <item android:state_pressed="true" android:drawable="@android:color/black"/>
    <item android:drawable="@android:color/white"/>
</selector>
```

Button

```
<Button
        android:id="@+id/btnRegister"
        android:layout_width="300dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_marginBottom="15dp"
        android:background="@drawable/main_button_background"
        android:text="register"
        android:textColor="@drawable/main_button_text_color" />
```

the result : [image: Button Image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this one:

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:state_focused="true" android:color="@android:color/black"/>
    <item android:state_pressed="true" android:color="@android:color/black"/>
    <item android:color="@android:color/white"/>
</selector>
```